# Finding a nonconstant function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm a little rusty on my complex analysis. I'm having trouble as to how to find nonconstant functions. If anyone can explain (in an elemetary way) how to get started on these problems, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you

A) Find a nonconstant function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ which is analytic on all of $\mathbb{C}$ with $f(1/2)=0$ and $f(1/3)=0$

B) Let $D=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1 \}$ be the open disk. Find a nonconstant function  $g: D \to D$ which is analytic on all of $D$ with $g(1/2)=0$ and $g(1/3)=0$.

My approach for A and B: Cross ratios formula?

C) Can the function $g$ in part $(b)$ be a fractional linear transformation?

Comment: For A) you can always use a polynomial function.

Comment: And for (B) one can use Mobius transforms; only one cannot simply pick one such function (why not?)

Comment: @User69127 I'm not sure what you mean by "any." You basically want $1/2$ and $1/3$ to be the zeros (or roots) of your function. Can you think of a way to construct a polynomial function that has those roots?

Comment: @Braindead sorry I had accidentally hit add comment. I did end up figuring out what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, let's say you'd like to have a function that has a zero at a point $a$. You can achieve this by having a factor of $(z-a)$. What would you have to do so that the function has a zero at both $a$ and $b$?

> $(z-a)(z-b)$

The second part of the problem is a bit trickier. You can't just use $z-a$, since you need to make sure that your function maps the unit disk into the unit disk.

However, note that $\dfrac{(z-a)}{1-\bar{a}z}$ maps the unit disk into itself, with the property that it has a zero at point $a$.

> $$\dfrac{(z-a)}{1-\bar{a}z}\dfrac{(z-b)}{1-\bar{b}z}$$
>
>  This works because both factors have norm less than one, and so their product also has norm less than 1.

Comment: My conjecture: $\dfrac{(z-1/2)(z-1/3)}{1-1/2z}$?

Comment: @User69127 Almost! You know that the first factor $(z-1/2)/(1-1/2z)$ belongs to the unit disk, but $(z-1/3)$ by itself may not belong to the unit disk!

Comment: @User69127 Hint: If $|w|<1$ and $|v|<1$, then $|wv| = |w| |v| < (1)(1) = 1$.

Comment: $\dfrac{(w-1/3)}{1-1/3w}$. Set them equal to each other and solve for $w$ in terms of $z$?

Comment: $f(z)=\dfrac{5z-1}{5-z}$

Comment: and for C, I put yes because any conformal map of a unit disk onto itself is a fractional linear transformation of the form $\dfrac{(z-a)}{1-\bar{a}z}$

Comment: @User69127 I have edited the post with answers in a spoiler box.

Comment: really awesome didn't know you could do spoiler box